# Can someone help me with the error in my python code?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I used `np.subtract ()` where I got the following error.

> Cannot convert input [(0, slice(None, None, None))] of type  to Timestamp

```
stock_open=panel_data['Open']
stock_close=panel_data['Close']
row,col=stock_close.shape
movements = np.zeros([row, col])
for i in range(0, row):
    movements[i,:] = np.subtract(stock_close[i,:], stock_open[i,:])
```

The below line in my code:

```
movements[i,:] = np.subtract(stock_close[i,:], stock_open[i,:])
```

gives me the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot convert input [(0, slice(None, None, None))] of type
>    to Timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below line

```
np.subtract(stock_close.values[i,:], stock_open.values[i,:])
```

or if you're looking for an even better way to do it :

```
stock_close.values[i,:] - stock_open.values[i,:]
```